# How to copy a whole column to the end of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

This might be an easy question, but I can't find the solution, I've searched in google but I only found the way to copy it to a new column, but not to an existing one.
Basically, if I have this two columns:

| Pilot1 | Pilot2 |
| --- | --- |
| Kevin | Tom |
| Russell | Richard |
| Max |  |

I just want to know how to move the whole column Pilot2 to the first one, and then delete it:

| Pilot1 |
| --- |
| Kevin |
| Russell |
| Max |
| Tom |
| Richard |

Comment: Are there columns in your dataframe *other* than these two?

Comment: And importantly, if yes, how should they be handled given the fact that extra rows are created?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
pd.concat([df["Pilot1"], df["Pilot2"]]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output -

```
0      Kevin
1    Russell
2        Max
3        Tom
4    Richard
5        NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: What if there are columns in the df *other* than Pilot1 and Pilot2?

Comment: @Nick The code above would only concat the specified columns. Not the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can `melt`:

```
(df
 .melt(value_name='Pilot1')
 .drop('variable', axis=1)
 .dropna()
 )
```

Output:

```
    Pilot1
0    Kevin
1  Russell
2      Max
3      Tom
4  Richard
```

Comment: What if there are columns in the df *other* than `Pilot1` and `Pilot2`?

Comment: @Nick this doesn't seem to be the case, but I would simply subset or use a id_vars depending on the desired output

Comment: Unfortunately the question isn't clear although it seems unlikely there are only the two columns... I have asked for clarification.